# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':background_location:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My app works fine when I run it or build app packages, but when I try to build apk for release or profile, it gives this message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':background_location:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\background_location-0.6.1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-15:37: AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
```

I've already tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair`, as well as updated my Gradle version. Also, I have AndroidX enabled.
Could somebody please help?

Update: I found a solution [here](https://github.com/Almoullim/background_location/issues/97)

Comment: Have you tried updating the `compileSdkVersion` to the latest (30) in the app gradle?

Comment: It was already 30 before I ran into this problem